# Why censor when we can filter to our liking?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Why not let the user decide if they want a question or answer that the admins censor to be seen  or not with content filtering? As it is it is just certain people who apparently decide for everyone. Why can't the admins decide the default and then the user can decide if they want to change the default for themselves?

Wouldn't this be good for admins too? Less complaints, less perceived oppression?

Comment: Is this the same as asking for an un-moderated site, i.e., are you asking moderators to permit anything and delete nothing?

Comment: Also if you want to discuss football, or politicians, or whatever, could you [use a Chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism) -- is that too much to ask?

Comment: As moderators its our job to ensure that Buddhism SE has *high-quality* content available. An [*off-topic / primarily opinion-based*](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/20603/buddhist-question-for-donald-trump) question with a score of -4 should not exist on the front page of the site. That is why I closed and deleted it. If you want to discuss such topics please do it in the chat room.

Answer (score 1):

This (what you're suggesting) would be a new feature of the web site (i.e. it's a feature which doesn't presently exist).

You can make new feature-requests by posting on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ -- when you post there, tag it `feature-request`.

Beware that there are [21,000 topics tagged 'feature-request'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), so ... I personally assume that new feature requests are usually unpopular and are rarely if ever chosen to be implemented (and so, generally, probably not worth the time or effort it takes to post a request for one).

Sorry if that's disappointing.

Comment: You don't *have* to, but if you *want* to suggest it then you want to. My own past experience is that it's fruitless to make feature-requests in general, and my guess is that this one wouldn't be implemented, but that needn't stop you from trying if you want to. I think you're essentially asking to be able to view (and maybe edit or add to) deleted content (i.e. content which moderators and/or other users have decided to close and/or delete).

Comment: Thank you Chris :) Ok, right but  do you know if it would    be that difficult to make a change like that? Already we can filter tags but that Isn't really the same thing.

Comment: Are you asking whether it's difficult for Stack Exchange to make a change like that? Yes and no. "No" because if they're able to make this site in the first place they obviously have the expertise to change it. "Yes" because they'd have to define the new feature, persuade people (Stack Exchange employees, users, and moderators) that it's a good idea, implement the change (perhaps on several platforms, i.e. on the server, in web browsers, and in their mobile applications) and test it. I think you're asking to let users choose to view closed/deleted topics, and add to them?

Comment: But closed/deleted topics include several categories: off-topic, but also spam, pornography, political rants, meta-questions about the site, intra-user hostility, etc. So I guess you only want to be able to work with "off-topic" content, and are OK with Stack Exchange wanting to delete spam etc.? But there are many other existing places for off-topic content (e.g. other Stack Exchange sites, or e.g. Chat). As I said my guess is that people (other users) won't want/vote to see this implemented, and even if they do then Stack Exchange won't do it.